# CTE over self join and sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

what are the advantage of CTE over self join and sub queries.
What ever we can implement using the self join /sub queries can be implemented also by using CTE. Wondering what are the benifts of using cte over those mentioned methods,apart from simple cte syntax!?

Comment: Some concrete examples would be helpful. Otherwise, the question is pretty broad.

Comment: What do you mean CTE over self join?  Please post an example.  And I think you mean derived table - not sub queries

Answer (score 1):

CTE's allow easy creation of recursive queries that navigate parent-child structures.

Answer (score -1):

When a query is truly complex (think the possibility of 5-6 derived tables and roughly 20 joins and 7 or more where conditions, you know - the average reporting query in an Enterprise environment) then the CTEs help make it easier to understand what is happening and thus make the query more maintainable. They may also make it much simpler to get the actual correct result when things work together in a complex manner.

So say I need a report of all the tecnnical information abut a bunch of orders that meet a certain criteria. Since the information would be summed, the end result should be the same number of records that you would get if you just queried the order table. So you start with a CTE that just gets the orders you want.  And you do a simple select from it and find there are 37 orders that meet the criteria. Now you know what your final results should be and as you make the query more and more complex, you can easily check to see that you didn't go wrong.

So now I need the sums of the individual items in each order. And maybe because they are stored in more than one table (say if services and goods were in separate tables) then you have a union that you need to get the sum for. So that becomes the second CTE.

Now you need the point of contact for the order but some orders have multiple people associated and you have to find the main contact by adding some criteria.  So now you have a third CTE.

Then you have two shipping addresses, so do you need both concatenated together or or should each shipment be a separate record? At this point it is easier to keep adding chunks of data through the used of multiple CTEs and when you get to the final query, it is relatively simple because all the complexity was in the individual chunk.

Then a year from now when someone needs to change the business rules for determining one chunk of information, you can change just that one part and be much more confident it didn't affect how the other pieces work together. So much easier to maintain.

And of course what @TabAllerman said about recursion.